# A simple fraction with a complex answer: possibly right under my nose

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions, algebraic-equations

I've been doing some calculations in fractions, and found this equation pop up to calculate my answer:

$$\frac{1-x}{1+x}=x$$

the initial equation is

$$\frac{2(x-1)}{\frac{4(x+1)}{2}}+x=4x+9(-4x-2)-2(-17x+34)+61+6$$

(I used a random number generator)I started tackling it by solving the right side

$$
\begin{align}
\cdots&=4x+9(-4x+2)-2(-17x+34)+61+6\\
&=4x+(-36x)+18-(-34x)-68+61+6\\
&=4x+(-36x)+18-(-34x)-68+61+6\\
&=4x-36x+1+34x-68+61+6\\
&=2x\\
\end{align}
$$

then i simplified it even further using the other side as well, getting:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{2(x-1)}{\frac{4(x+1)}{2}}+x&=2x\\
\frac{2(x-1)}{2(x+1)}+x&=2x\\
\frac{x-1}{x+1}+x&=2x\\
\frac{x-1}{x+1}&=x\\
\end{align}
$$

This is my problem. so what is $x???$  also, did I do this correctly? if not, could you solve the equation for me, and then still solve this annoying equation?

Comment: The lines after "I started tackling it by solving the right side" are wrong as well — 61(x+1) should expand to 61x+61

Comment: @TobyMak i made an error, and changed it back to normal.  thanks for pointing it out

Comment: $4x+9(-4x-2)-2(-17x+34)+61+6=2x-19$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{x-1}{x+1} = x$$
Multiply both sides by $x+1:$
$$
x-1 = x(x+1)
$$
$$
x-1 = x^2 + x
$$
$$
-1 = x^2
$$
$$\text{etc.}
$$

Comment: great, great!!  my soultion is not even real!!    i now gotta change my 'real analysis' tag

Comment: If you replace "etc." with "$x=\pm i$", you have a complete answer lol

Comment: also, good call on the \cdots idea. i didn't know it existed!

Comment: @AlexanderDay : Actually this is neither real analysis nor complex analysis; rather it is algebra. Real analysis deals with limits and continuity and integration and differentiation, and complex analysis deals with consequences of the holomorphic nature of complex-valued functions of a complex variable. $$ \S $$ As for typography, I use \ldots between commas, as in $1,\ldots, n,$ and \cdots between binary relation or binary operation signs as in $A+\cdots+Z$ or $A < B < \cdots < Z.$ \vdots and \ddots also exist and are sometimes used in matrices.

Answer (score 0):

The right hand side of the equation is $$x-19$$ not $2x $ as you wrote.

the equation is

$$\frac {x-1}{x+1}=x-19$$

Comment: sorry, and thanks.  but this is a comment, not an answer

Comment: you right member seems not correct.

Comment: $1-68+61+6=67-67=0$, which gets $2x\pm 0$